# Questions method does not return answers

Tags: bug, status-completed

I think questions method also return answers too and the help page says so

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions

```
....
"answers": [
    {
      "answer_id": {
        "description": "id of the answer",
        "values": "number",
        "optional": false
      },
      "accepted": {
        "description": "whether this answer is the accepted answer on its question",
        "values": "boolean",
        "optional": false
      },
      "answer_comments_url": {
        "description": "a link to the method that returns comments on this answer",
        "values": "string",
        "optional": false
      },
      ....
```

But now, I don't see answers on question method.

Is that intentional or Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a bug, and will be corrected on the next code push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.