# api.stackoverflow/0.8/questions now gives answers as well by default?

Tags: feature-request

Up until now, `/questions` hasn't given the answers to the questions by default - you'd have to get the question ID and then use that to get the answers to the question. This means the size of the JSON file has increased quite a lot. Also, this change does not follow the pattern of leaving out non-question data - now, comments and bodies are not included, but answers are.

I think the details of the answers should not be included in the questions page unless deliberately asked for by using a parameter like `?answers=true`.

Also, the documentation is not helpful. The sample in the "returns" section looks nothing like what is actually returned; it looks more like the JSON version of the help page.

Ultimately the answers need to be able to be turned off using parameters, even if it's opt-out (though personally I think it should be opt-in, as you accessed `/questions` and therefore asked for *questions*).

Comment: This kind of needs to be sorted because ever since this changed my app now takes 3 times longer to load the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supposed to include answers (probably first page only), and [documented](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions) (look for "answers" in  return json), but there was a [bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/340/questions-method-does-not-return-answers), and it has been fixed recently.

But yes, I also think `answer=true` option would be nice.

Comment: Well as I have said the comments and body are opt-in so it follows that answers should be as well.

Comment: ++ for answer=true. seems a no brainer.